# PHP - string parsing & concatenation problems

Tags: php, parsing

Here is the problem : I want to split a string to have the name and the first name, but my two variable are empty and i don't understant why... Can someone help me ? This my code :

```
 $nom_aut1 = "";
 $prenom_aut2 = "";
 //$auteur1 is already initialized

  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($auteur1); ++$i)
  {
    if ($auteur1[$i] != ' ') continue;

    for ($j = 0; $j < $i; ++$j)
    {
      $nom_aut1 .= $auteur[$j];
    }

    for ($j = $i+1; $j < strlen($auteur1); ++$j)
    {
      $nom_aut1 .= $auteur1[$j];
    }

    break;
  }
  echo '"'.$nom_aut1.'.'.$prenom_aut1.'"';
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried the PHP function explode()? I think that one is way more suitable for you to do things like this.

Comment: How does the input string look like?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? I think there might be a better way (without such loop / break / continue structure). If anything - it looks like your code stops after first letter, as break is issued.

Comment: You should check if you didn’t mix up your variables (`$nom_aut1`, `$prenom_aut2`, `$auteur1`, `$auteur`, and `$prenom_aut1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to split a name into first and last name based on a space? Why not just do this:

```
$names = explode(" ",$name);
```

If `$name = "Hello World"`

`$names` will be an array such that

```
$names[0] = "Hello"
$names[1] = "World"
```

This way, if there is a middle name, you can get that as well.

You can do it this way:

```
$names = explode(" ",$name);

if (count($names) == 1) //only first name
{
    $first = $names[0];
    $last = "";
}
else if (count($names) == 2) //only first and last name
{
    $first = $names[0];
    $last = $names[1];
}
else    //one or more middle names were provided
{
    $first = $names[0];
    $last = $names[count($names)-1];

    for($i=1;$i<count($names)-1;$i++)
        $middle .= $names[$i] . ' ';
    $middle = trim($middle);  
}
```

So, if `$name = "Hello Foo Bar World"`

```
$first = "Hello"
$last = "World"
$middle = "Foo Bar"
```

Comment: It's exactly what i wanted to do.
Thank's you, it's gonna lighten my code :)

Comment: It’s not exactly the same, but `explode(" ",$name, 2)` would be.

Comment: @Hahuha: Edited to show how you can pick up middle names as well, if you need

Comment: @Gumbo: I wasn't sure if he wanted just the last name, or both.

Comment: @Gumbo and xbonez : I just want to have the first name and the rest.  Is explode() split the string at the first space found ?

Comment: `explode` will split the string at every space found, and return an array of all the pieces. So `Welcome to stack overflow` will return an array with 4 elements, each word as one element.

Comment: @Hahuha: if you want only first name, and the rest as last, then what you want is the line Gumbo posted: `explode(" ",$name, 2)`. This will return an array with just two elements. The first name as the first element, and everything else as the second element.

Comment: Okay perfect, i can manage this now. Thanks you all ! (I love this website)

Answer (score 1):

If the letter is not equal to ' ' it continue the loop and does not execute the 2 for loops.

But you are looking for the [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function in PHP:

```
<?php
  $names = explode(' ', $name);
  $prenom = $names[0];
  $nom = $names[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, double check all your variable names.

You are saying:

```
$nom_aut1 = "";
$prenom_aut2 = "";
```

You are not using $prenom_aut2 anywhere in your code and then you are echoing:

```
echo '"'.$nom_aut1.'.'.$prenom_aut1.'"';
```

In answer to your specific question, you are declaring, populating and echoing different variables.

Comment: You're right, I made some mistake when i ask my question. Plus, I just noticed that in my second inner loop, i was concatenated $nom_aut1 instead of $prenom_aut1. But with these answers, my code has completely changed

Comment: Absolutely, the method suggested is more appropriate, I was just answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to explode and manipulate this way!.

```
list($first_name, $last_name) = explode(" ", $name);
echo $first_name; 
echo $last_name;
```